# How to add binary third party libraries in qt creator (Ubuntu-sdk verison of QT-Creator)

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, c++, qt-creator

I try to write an app for ubuntu unity8 and i use a third party library in that app.

My problem is that i would like to use the binary version of that library in my app and not the source files of it.

How can i add the binary version of that library into qtcreator so that the library is accessible in my cpp files in the app via:

`#include <header.h>`

I tried by using `add_library(binary_file)` in the CMakeLists.txt .
But that did not work.

So i need to know, what is the correct way to use third party binary libraries in a ubuntu unity 8 app. What files do i need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

Adding `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Projectname library)` to CMakeLists.txt made it run.